# Find only first class with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the following markup, I want to find **only the first** element with class `.hide` and change its class by clicking on `.add a`.

But I am unable to locate the class.

```
<div class="field">default</div>
<div class="field hide">find this 1</div>
<div class="field hide">and then this 2</div>
<div class="field hide">and then this 3 </div>
<div class="field hide">and then this 4</div>
<div class="field add"><a>Add more</a></div>
```

Here's what I'm trying:

```
$('.add a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();                     
    $(this).parent().siblings().find(".hide").removeClass("hide").addClass("show");
});
```

**JSFiddle:**
http://jsfiddle.net/ok38wrnt/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`find` is wrong under `siblings()` as the siblings are the items you want.

Use a `filter` instead:

You can then just add `:first` to the `.hide` to get the first match.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/ok38wrnt/2/

```
$('.add a').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().siblings().filter(".hide:first").removeClass("hide").addClass("show");

});
```

which shortens to:

http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/ok38wrnt/5/

```
 $(this).parent().siblings(".hide:first").removeClass("hide").addClass("show");
```

You *could* probably use `toggleClass` instead, assuming you can never have both classes missing (or you will wind up with both set).

Answer (score 2):

Use `:eq` selector with index 0 to target only first element:

```
$(this).parent().siblings(".hide:eq(0)")
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9L4smL6v/)**

Comment: Does not work... `find()` is for descendants. The siblings *are* the elements to match.

Answer (score 1):

The `.hide` elements are siblings of the `a` elements' parent, so you should use `siblings()` with a selector. You'll also need to use `:first` to match the first found element. Try this:

```
$('.add a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().siblings('.hide:first').toggleClass("hide show");
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ok38wrnt/4/)

Answer (score 1):

Jquery also offers `first()` method.

```
$('.add a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();                     
          $('.hide').first().removeClass("hide").addClass("show");

});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8nskx6b1/)